# Cmd syntax to remotely execute a command through SSH

Tags: ssh

I would like to start up an application server that resides on another linux machine in another network, so SSH is required. How can I do it? Something like this?:

```
ssh user@host password /home/user/server/bin/run.sh
```

?

Comment: Something like this, except the "password" part. You can't give a password to `ssh` in command line. Use keys to authenticate without password. (Don't use `sshpass` utility which provides a way around this).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a ssh public/private key pair using `ssh-keygen` command, and then append your public key to .ssh/authorized_keys file of target host, then you can omit the 'password' part above.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host:.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh user@host
chmod og-rw .ssh/authorized_keys 
chmod a-x .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 .ssh
```